# How to store MySQL response into a table after executing a query?

Tags: mysql

When I executes a query on MySQL workbench I get the results of that query. If there was an error then it gives you an error code along with some data. If it passes then it returns the total records inserted/updates/ total warning and a list of all warnings.

I have a stored procedure that executes `INSERT INTO ...... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

What I need to do is to create a table that will store all the results returned after every query execution.

I can want to capture the following

1. total inserts
2. total updates
3. total warning
4. if there are warning then I would like to capture all the notes
   returned by MySQL.
5. if there is an error in the query for what every reason then I need
   to capture the error output.

The reason why I need to do this is because this procedure is triggered by an event. So I need to know what happened on a daily bases so I can investigate error/warning.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So... this is a bit late here, but I will give this a go.

If anyone else is looking for something like this...

I believe what you are looking for is `performance_schema`

If you have that option in your version of mysql.

*(currently using AWS/RDS 5.6.34-log at this time ).*

You can look thru the tables after you have it on and see the performance, locks inserts, updates, warnings(granted you have your `sql_mode` set), and other various things that I believe you are desiring.

There are a slew of things in it, but it taxes heavily on the mysql that already seems to have issues, at least what i have see using the `out of the box` settings from amazon.

Examples:

```
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.events_statements_history LIMIT 1000;
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.events_statements_history_long LIMIT 1000;
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.mutex_instances LIMIT 1000;
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.events_waits_current LIMIT 1000;
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name LIMIT 1000;
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.events_stages_summary_by_host_by_event_name LIMIT 1000;
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.events_stages_summary_by_thread_by_event_name LIMIT 1000;
```

> Not affiliated or associated with the companies below.

[MySQL Documents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema-quick-start.html)

[datadoghq ref: on setting up performance_schema for AWS](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-collect-rds-mysql-metrics/)